# Python parsing JSON from url incomplete

Tags: python, json, url

I am trying to get a JSON from a URL I have succeeded in doing that but when I print the result it seems like I get only half of the content.

this is what I wrote:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen("https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/company/stock/list") as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    print(data)
```

I won't print what I am getting because it's very long(if you look at the source and ctrl+f look up the sentence you will find that its in the middle of the page) but it starts with 
`ties Municipal Fund', 'price': 9.83,`

thanks for the help.

Comment: I tried to run your code on Jupyter and it seems I can print the whole json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your output has been cut by your IDE.

When I run the same request and I write it into a file, you can see the that the data is fully written:

```
import requests
with requests.get("https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/company/stock/list") as url:
    data = url.content.decode()
    with open("file.txt","w") as f:
        f.write(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

When the response is large, the first read may only return *what is available at that time*. If you want to be sure to have the full data, you should loop reading until you get nothing (an empty byte string here).

Here, it would probably be more robust to pass the response stream to `json.load` and let it read until the json string is completed:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(
        "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/company/stock/list") as url:
    data = json.load(url)
    print(data)
```

But I think that if the data was partial, `json.loads` should have choked on it. So the problem is likely elsewhere...

Comment: @bikoman57: this is the evidence that the problem is not is the load part but in the display one...